# How to enable multiple TinyMCE in the same form

Tags: tinymce

I want to use 2 different textareas with tinyMCE in the same form. The first one works well but whenever I am adding the 2nd one, the 2nd one disabled (it enables when I enlarge it manually from bottom right corner). Their field name and id is different.[image]

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your full tinymce configs

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no code from you we cant figure out where your problem is. Maybe to go a way around, init TinyMce for both Textareas over a class:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector : "mceSimple"
});

tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        editor_selector : "mceAdvanced"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
        <textarea name="content1" class="mceSimple" style="width:100%">
        </textarea>
        <textarea name="content2" class="mceAdvanced" style="width:100%">
        </textarea>
</form>
```

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to use editor of same theme (simple).

Answer (score 1):

If you resize the tinymce's area, the text magically appears.

Mikko Huilaja's javascript solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function() { 
  forceTinyMceIframeResize(); 
});

function forceTinyMceIframeResize() { 
  $('.mceEditor .mceIframeContainer iframe').each(function(i) { 
    $(this).height($(this).height()+1); 
  }); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: I know, clicking on bottom right corner of the editor or resizing gives the solution but site user may not understand this. Anyway, thanks for your ans.

Answer (score 0):

Use a common class (e.g tinymce-editor) for all the text area for which you need to add TinyMCE.

Then in HTML head section add the following code to initialize TinyMCE.

```
$(function(){
   tinyMCE.init({
    selector: '.tinymce-editor',
    statusbar: false,
    min_height: 120,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'styleselect | bold italic underline | undo redo | image | link',
    plugins: 'image, link',
    forced_root_block: false,
    default_link_target: "_blank",
    link_assume_external_targets: true 
   });
});
```