# TinyMCE and Firefox 11

Tags: javascript, firefox, tinymce

As most of you know, Firefox 11 update was released few days ago.
After the release I was notified that there was some strange behavior in our web app.
We have multiple instances of TinyMCE on a single page and only the first instance works as it should. The other instances don't seem to be editable to the naked eye, but in fact changes made to the "other" instances will be saved on submit.

After a nice google session I noticed other people had this same problem but in most cases the solution was to update Tiny to 3.5b2 (I'm currently using 3.37), or removing/adding some plugins. Neither worked for me.

I also noticed that when Tiny is manually resized, the text gets rendered and the resized instance works fine.

Anyone?

**UPDATE:** I made a fresh web page with multiple instances (ver. 3.5b2) and everything worked perfectly on FF11. The problem seems to be somewhere else in our web app. I will post this as an answer in a few hours.

Comment: Ohh shit, i updated my firefox 1min ago and i do not have those issues. I initialsed every TinyBox over JQuery via a class attribut, maybe that helps. I will keep my eyes open. Cheers

Comment: Is there a way to initialize each instance? Can I loop through the Tiny's and call a init function for each of them?

Comment: Yeah of course i posted a way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783141/how-to-enable-multiple-tinymce-in-the-same-form/9805627#9805627

Comment: you can loop through the editors using the array tinymce.editors

Comment: I'm not seeing how I can do it though. I would like to do something like this:
loop
   editors[i].init();

Comment: @Thariama how would I access this array?

Comment: aah, sry there was misunderstanding. You can loop though the editor objects after they have been created, but then there is no use to call an init function at that point of time. You could try to initialize your editor using the mceAddControl execCommand (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Command_identifiers) - maybe that helps

Comment: shit, I'm using django-tinymce and met the same problem. There are four TinyMCE editors in one Web page, and only the last one can accept user input. And something is strange, after restoring or maximizing the FF 11 window, the rest three work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fresh web page with multiple instances (ver. 3.5b2) and everything worked perfectly on FF11. The problem seems to be somewhere else in our web app.

Answer (score 4):

Add this script just before body tag closing

```
jQuery(window).load( function() {
    jQuery(".mceEditor .mceLayout").each(function(i,ele){
        jQuery("#"+ele.id).css('width',jQuery("#"+ele.id).width()+10)
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the reason behind increasing the width of the control?

Answer (score 1):

solution without jquery

```
try {
    function addEvent(obj, evType, fn){ 
        if (obj.addEventListener){ 
            obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false); 
            return true; 
        } else if (obj.attachEvent){ 
            var r = obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn); 
            return r; 
        } else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
    addEvent(window, 'load', function() {
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('mceEditor');
        for (d in divs) {
            var iframes = divs[d].getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            for (i in iframes) {
                iframes[i].style.width = iframes[i].style.width = '500px';
            }
        }
    }
    );
} catch(err) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for my 3.3.9.3 (thanks Thomas for your input):

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $('.mceEditor').hover(function(){
        el  = $('.mceFirst iframe');
        el_w  = el.width();
        el.css("width",el_w+1);
        el.css("width",el_w-1);
    });
});
```